# Authentication between 1st party app and REST backend?

Tags: android, ios, rest, authentication, mobile

1. I have my own REST API ("backend")
2. I have my own (first party/trusted app) mobile app for that ("frontend")
3. I want my users to be able to login via a form directly in mobile app (not via a browser etc.)

For that case, what is the current state of the art for the authentication? Would one just hash the user credentials and place them into the header when calling the REST API? Or is there a more secure way?

Comment: If your app is able to process http redirects (like browsers do) then take a look at OAuth2/OIDC. If your app to server connection is secure then basic auth at login and JWT (Bearer token) thereafter allows for stateless server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are more secure ways.

One mechanism is called [challenge-response authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication).
The server sends a challenge to the client (for example a random number).
The client responses with `hash_function(random_number + password)`.
So the client concatenates the random number and the password and then creates  a hash of it. The server calculates the same value and so the server knows if the password is right. Even if someone recorded the plain text stream he cannot spoof the password nor a hash which can be used to login.

What I explained about challenge-response authentication requires the server to store the password in plain text. But Wikipedia says there is a way to make it work without storing the password in plain text at the server. Because it's better to store salted password hashes only (in the server DB) in the case someone leaks the database.

Here is a list of login methods and I suppose `OAuth2` is state of the art (because I remember to have seen `oauth` in the URL when you login to a GMail account in Thunderbird):

https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.AuthenticationMethods.html